# purpose of .bind(this) at end of ajax callback?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

From the reactjs tutorial, what's the purpose of having `.bind(this)` at the end of the ajax callback? Does code work correctly without it?

```
        data: JSON.stringify({text: text}),
        success: function (data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
```

Comment: Something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function). Without `.bind(this)` the `this` reference becomes null when used inside a custom function (defined in a reactJs component) .

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It ensure's `this` will be the correct object inside the callback.  See [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

An alternative specific to react is to do:

```
myAjaxFunction: function(){
  $.getJSON('/something', this.handleData);
},
handleData: function(data){
  this.setState({data: data});
}
```

This works because React handles binding of component methods for you.

If you ran your original code in without bind, you'd get this error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` because `this === window` in the callback;

or in strict mode: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`, where `this === undefined` in the callback.

Comment: The part "specific to React" is possible because of autobinding added in 0.4: [Autobind by Default](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html).

Comment: Also found this handy article explaining the use cases for the bind, apply, and call methods - http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of having `.bind(this)` at the end of the ajax callback is let `this` be related to your react class. In other words you can add:

```
var self = this;
```

outside of ajax and it works the same.
You code equal to:

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
    .
    .
    data: JSON.stringify({text: text}),
    success: function (data) {
        self.setState({data: data});
    },
    .
    .
});
```