# React: "this" is undefined inside a component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

```
class PlayerControls extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loopActive: false,
      shuffleActive: false,
    }
  }

  render() {
    var shuffleClassName = this.state.toggleActive ? "player-control-icon active" : "player-control-icon"

    return (
      <div className="player-controls">
        <FontAwesome
          className="player-control-icon"
          name='refresh'
          onClick={this.onToggleLoop}
          spin={this.state.loopActive}
        />
        <FontAwesome
          className={shuffleClassName}
          name='random'
          onClick={this.onToggleShuffle}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  onToggleLoop(event) {
    // "this is undefined??" <--- here
    this.setState({loopActive: !this.state.loopActive})
    this.props.onToggleLoop()
  }
```

I want to update `loopActive` state on toggle, but `this` object is undefined in the handler. According to the tutorial doc, I `this` should refer to the component. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

ES6 `React.Component` doesn't auto bind methods to itself. You need to bind them yourself in `constructor`. Like this:

```
constructor (props){
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
      loopActive: false,
      shuffleActive: false,
    };
  
  this.onToggleLoop = this.onToggleLoop.bind(this);

}
```

Comment: if you change your onClick property to `() => this.onToggleLoop` after moving the onToggleLoop function into your react class it will work as well.

Comment: Do you really have to bind every method of every react class? Isn't that a little crazy?

Comment: @AlexL There are ways to do it without explicitly binding the methods. if you use babel it's possible to declare every method on React component as arrow functions. There are examples here: https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus

Comment: But why is `this` undefined in the first place? I know `this` in Javascript depends on how the function is called, but what's going on in here?

Comment: but how can i do this is the function is not defined until after the constructor? I get a "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" if i try to do this in the constructor even thou my function is defined on the class :(

Comment: @Ivan the article is actually at: https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/07/07/react-on-es6-plus and thanks for that information it was exactly what I was looking for! :D

Comment: TLDR for the article: use arrow  functions instead.

Comment: I found making `onClick` point to `function.bind(this)` instead of just `function` was the least intrusive fix. I could keep my React classes the same.

Comment: I found I had to bind my `onClick` property slightly differently to @Sam . In the example shown it would be `onClick={ () => { this.onToggleLoop(); }}` - in general im with the "Isn't this a little crazy" crowd.

Comment: why is `this` `undefined`, for click event listener, `this` would refer to the element on which the lsitener is registered, so technically wouldnt it refer to a html element and not `undefined`?????

Answer (score 109):

There are a couple of ways.

One is to add 
`this.onToggleLoop = this.onToggleLoop.bind(this);` in the constructor.

Another is arrow functions 
`onToggleLoop = (event) => {...}`.

And then there is `onClick={this.onToggleLoop.bind(this)}`.

Comment: Why does onToogleLoop = () => {} work?

I got the same problem and I bindet it in my constructor but it didnt work ... and now i have seen your post and replace my method with a arrow function syntax and it works. Can you explain it to me ?

Comment: from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions; An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used.

Comment: Note that binding inline in the `onClick` will return a new function every render and thus it looks like a new value has been passed for the prop, messing with `shouldComponentUpdate` in `PureComponent`s.

Answer (score 37):

Write your function this way:

```
onToggleLoop = (event) => {
    this.setState({loopActive: !this.state.loopActive})
    this.props.onToggleLoop()
}
```

[Fat Arrow Functions](http://www.react.express/fat_arrow_functions)

> the binding for the keyword this is the same outside and inside the fat arrow function. This is different than functions declared with function, which can bind this to another object upon invocation. Maintaining the this binding is very convenient for operations like mapping: this.items.map(x => this.doSomethingWith(x)).

Comment: If I do that I get `ReferenceError: fields are not currently supported`.

Comment: It works if inside the constructor I say this.func = () => { ... }, but I regard that as kind of goofy and want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: So terrible that you can't use normal class syntax in React!

Answer (score 12):

I ran into a similar bind in a render function and ended up passing the context of `this` in the following way:

```
{someList.map(function(listItem) {
  // your code
}, this)}
```

I've also used:

```
{someList.map((listItem, index) =>
    <div onClick={this.someFunction.bind(this, listItem)} />
)}
```

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary functions you're creating there, each and every time the list is rendered...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes it's true these functions are created afresh each time render is called. It's better to create the functions as class methods and bind them once to the class, but for beginners the manual context binding may be helpful

Answer (score 4):

in my case this was the solution **= () => {}**

```
methodName = (params) => {
//your code here with this.something
}
```

Comment: this is the real solution. Forgot to put it on the one function that was failing me

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should notice that `this` depends on how function is invoked
ie: when a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

`this` is accessible in JSX context as your component object, so you can call your desired method inline as `this` method.

If you just pass reference to function/method, it seems that react will invoke it as independent function.

```
onClick={this.onToggleLoop} // Here you just passing reference, React will invoke it as independent function and this will be undefined

onClick={()=>this.onToggleLoop()} // Here you invoking your desired function as method of this, and this in that function will be set to object from that function is called ie: your component object
```

Comment: Right, you can even use the first line i.e. `onClick={this.onToggleLoop}` provided that in your component class you have defined a field (property) `onToggleLoop = () => /*body using 'this'*/`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using babel, you bind 'this' using ES7 bind operator
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-function-bind#auto-self-binding

```
export default class SignupPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    const data = { 
      email: this.refs.email.value,
    } 
  }

  render() {

    const {errors} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="view-container registrations new">
        <main>
          <form id="sign_up_form" onSubmit={::this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="field">
              <input ref="email" id="user_email" type="email" placeholder="Email"  />
            </div>
            <div className="field">
              <input ref="password" id="user_password" type="new-password" placeholder="Password"  />
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
          </form>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to give an explanation of why `this` is undefined:
If we use `this` in a function that is not an arrow function, `this` is bound to a global object when not in strict mode. But with strict mode, `this` will be undefined (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp).

And ES6 modules are always in strict mode ([javascript: use strict is unnecessary inside of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386015/javascript-use-strict-is-unnecessary-inside-of-modules)).

You can bind `this` in `onToggleLoop` function with the instance of `PlayerControls` component by using `bind` method inside the constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      loopActive: false,
      shuffleActive: false,
    }

    this.onToggleLoop = this.onToggleLoop.bind(this)
}
```

Or use the arrow function instead:

```js
onToggleLoop = (event) => {
    this.setState({loopActive: !this.state.loopActive})
    this.props.onToggleLoop()
}
```

The arrow function does not have context, so `this` in the arrow function will represent the object that defined the arrow function.

Comment: Add something about being able to bind this to provide context. The concept of this in JS can be very confusing and generally requires a lot more explication.

Answer (score 0):

If you call **your created method** in the lifecycle methods like componentDidMount... then you can only use the `this.onToggleLoop = this.onToogleLoop.bind(this)` and the fat arrow function `onToggleLoop = (event) => {...}`.

The normal approach of the declaration of a function in the constructor wont work because the lifecycle methods are called earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for a stateless component that received the ref with forwardRef, I had to do what it is said here https://itnext.io/reusing-the-ref-from-forwardref-with-react-hooks-4ce9df693dd

From this (onClick doesn't have access to the equivalent of 'this')

```
const Com = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} onClick={() => {console.log(ref.current} } />
})
```

To this (it works)

```
const useCombinedRefs = (...refs) => {
  const targetRef = React.useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    refs.forEach(ref => {
      if (!ref) return

      if (typeof ref === 'function') ref(targetRef.current)
      else ref.current = targetRef.current
    })
  }, [refs])

  return targetRef
}

const Com = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const innerRef = useRef()
  const combinedRef = useCombinedRefs(ref, innerRef)

  return <input ref={combinedRef } onClick={() => {console.log(combinedRef .current} } />
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite how your onToggleLoop method is called from your render() method.

```
render() {
    var shuffleClassName = this.state.toggleActive ? "player-control-icon active" : "player-control-icon"

return (
  <div className="player-controls">
    <FontAwesome
      className="player-control-icon"
      name='refresh'
      onClick={(event) => this.onToggleLoop(event)}
      spin={this.state.loopActive}
    />       
  </div>
    );
  }
```

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers) shows this pattern in making calls to functions from expressions in attributes.

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran into "this is undefined" error The method below worked for me. I passed the state to my class constructor and had to simply pass the function being used as an arrow function to my listener.

```
const cartUtils: CartUtils = new CartUtils(cartItems, setCartItems);

onClick={(evt) => cartUtils.getProductInfo(evt)}
```