# Creating custom function in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component

```
export default class Archive extends React.Component { 
   ...
}
```

`componentDidMount` and `onClick` methods partially use the same code, except for slight change in parameters.

Is it possible to create a function inside the component class so it can be reused in the scope of the component?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can create functions in react components. It is actually regular [ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which inherits from `React.Component`. Just be careful and bind it to the correct context in `onClick` event:

```
export default class Archive extends React.Component { 

    saySomething(something) {
        console.log(something);
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        this.saySomething("element clicked");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.saySomething("component did mount");
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} value="Click me" />;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you want to do recursive call of a function? How do you call that within the function?

Comment: @Norfeldt as simple as non-recursive call, just call the method/function `this.myMethod()`

Comment: For me just `this.handleClick` works for me to invoke a custom function defined in my react component. What is this additional syntax `.bind(this)`? Why do we need it?

Comment: @RBT sure, it will invoke the function. The problem is that `this` inside the method will not be what you would expect. See more about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function

Comment: In my implementation I get that `bind(this)` should not be used in a JSX component. any alternative to access the props from a custom function without binding `this` context?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo bind the function only once, in constructor

Answer (score 38):

Another way:

```
export default class Archive extends React.Component { 

  saySomething = (something) => {
    console.log(something);
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.saySomething("element clicked");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.saySomething("component did mount");
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick} value="Click me" />;
  }
}
```

In this format you don't need to use `bind`

Comment: Can I try to access these local functions, from a different component?? I mean can we export such a function, actually I am getting error

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. I would just create a function in another file, and call the function in both (or more) places. In my example above, I would add a `saySomething.js` and export `saySomething` there.

Then in both of components you `import saySomething` and then call the function.

The advantage of this approach is `saySomething` can be unit tested in separation and you have 2 independent components that just so happen using some same code instead of tangle them together

Comment: It's not even working for me this. I am getting _saySomething is not a function_ on the very declaration line. I need to use old way of ES5 `function() { ... }` or declare the function in another file.

Answer (score 13):

You can try this.

```
// Author: Hannad Rehman Sat Jun 03 2017 12:59:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

import React from 'react';
import RippleButton from '../../Components/RippleButton/rippleButton.jsx';

class HtmlComponents extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.rippleClickFunction=this.rippleClickFunction.bind(this);
    }

    rippleClickFunction(){
        //do stuff. 
        // foo==bar
    }

    render() {
      return (
         <article>
             <h1>React Components</h1>
             <RippleButton onClick={this.rippleClickFunction}/>
         </article>
      );
   }
}

export default HtmlComponents;
```

Yhe only concern is you have to bind the context to the function

Answer (score 4):

With React Functional way

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const App = () => {
  const saySomething = (something) => {
    console.log(something);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    saySomething("from useEffect");
  });
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    saySomething("element clicked");
  };
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClick}>
      Hello World
    </Button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-meadow-gm9g0

Comment: Is this actually ok? Or is there a performance overhead? I kinda assumed you'd have to declare the methods outside of the component function

Comment: I think you'd need to use useCallback to stop the function being redefined everytime. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138145/functions-in-stateless-components