# Where should functions in function components go?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm trying to convert this cool `<canvas>` animation I found [here](https://blog.alexwendland.com/2015/particle-network-js-animations/) into a React reusable component. It looks like this component would require one parent component for the canvas, and many children components for the `function Ball()`.

It would probably be better for performance reasons to make the `Balls` into stateless components as there will be many of them. I'm not as familiar with making stateless components and wondered where I should define the `this.update()` and `this.draw` functions defined in `function Ball()`.

Do functions for stateless components go inside the component or outside? In other words, which of the following is better?

1:

```
const Ball = (props) => {
    const update = () => {
        ...
    }

    const draw = () => {
        ...
    }

    return (
       ...
    );
}
```

2:

```
function update() {
     ...
}

function draw() {
     ...
}

const Ball = (props) => {
    return (
       ...
    );
}
```

What are the pros and cons of each and is one of them better for specific use cases such as mine?

Comment: Can you post the existing code so we see how it will get used?

Comment: @Scimonster I posted it in an embedded link, maybe you missed it. Here's the link: https://codepen.io/awendland/pen/XJExGv

Answer (score 228, accepted):

The first thing to note is that stateless functional components cannot have methods: You shouldn't count on calling `update` or `draw` on a rendered `Ball` if it is a stateless functional component.

In most cases you should declare the functions outside the component function so you declare them only once and always reuse the same reference. When you declare the function inside, every time the component is rendered the function will be defined again.

There are cases in which you will need to define a function inside the component to, for example, assign it as an event handler that behaves differently based on the properties of the component. But still you could define the function outside `Ball` and bind it with the properties, making the code much cleaner and making the `update` or `draw` functions reusable:

```js
// you can use update somewhere else
const update = (propX, a, b) => { ... };
    
const Ball = props => (
  <Something onClick={update.bind(null, props.x)} />
);
```

If you're using **hooks**, you can use `useCallback` to ensure the function is only redefined when any of its dependencies change (`props.x` in this case):

```js
const Ball = props => {
  const onClick = useCallback((a, b) => {
    // do something with a, b and props.x
  }, [props.x]);

  return (
    <Something onClick={onClick} />
  );
}
```

This is **the wrong way**:

```js
const Ball = props => {
  function update(a, b) {
    // props.x is visible here
  }
    
  return (
    <Something onClick={update} />
  );
}
```

When using `useCallback`, defining the `update` function in the `useCallback` hook itself or outside the component becomes a design decision more than anything: You should take into account if you're going to reuse `update` and/or if you need to access the scope of the component's closure to, for example, read/write to the state. Personally I choose to define it inside the component by default and make it reusable only if the need arises, to prevent over-engineering from the start. On top of that, reusing application logic is better done with more specific hooks, leaving components for presentational purposes. Defining the function outside the component while using hooks really depends on the grade of decoupling from React you want for your application logic.

Another [common discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289811/function-inside-functional-component-in-react-hooks-performance) about `useCallback` is whether to always use it for every function or not. That is, treat is as *opt-in* or *always recommendable*. I would argue to always use `useCallback`: I've seen many bugs caused by not wrapping a function in `useCallback` and not a single scenario where doing so affects the performance or logic in any way. In most cases, you want to keep a reference while the dependencies don't change, so you can use the function itself as a dependency for other effects, memos or callback. In many cases the callback will be passed as a prop to other elements, and if you memoized it with `useCallback` you won't change the props (thus re-render) other components independently of how cheap or costly that would be. I've seen many thousands of functions declared in components and not a single case in which using `useCallback` would have any down side. On the other hand most functions not memoized with `useCallback` would eventually be changed to do so, causing serious bugs or performance issues if the developer doesn't recognize the implications of not doing so. *Technically* there is a performance hit by using `useCallback`, as you would be creating and additional function but it is negligible compared to the re-declaration of the function that always has to happen either you use `useCallback` or not and the overall footprint of React and JavaScript. So, if you are really concerned about the performance impact of `useCallback` versus not using it, you should be questioning yourself if React is the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Marco, that clears things up a bit. The thing I'm confused about in my case is related to the `this.draw` function inside the `Ball`. It uses the `ctx` from what would be the parent's `<canvas>` and also uses the `this` keyword for what would be the child `Ball` component. What would be the best way to integrate implement the stateless component so both of those properties are accessible?

Comment: there is no `this` when using stateless functional components, have that in mind. For the canvas context, you would have to pass it to every single `Ball`, that doesn't sound good at all.

Comment: So in this case it would be best to just have no child component you're saying?

Comment: Not only that but, why would you use a React component inside a canvas? You could just paint in the canvas.

Comment: I wanted to make this whole canvas a reusable component to get practice with react.

Comment: The React component would just render a canvas, everything else would be practically the same as it is in the original, all the heavy lifting is done on the canvas rendering context, not on the DOM. And you will need a classical component, because you need to know when the canvas mounted to get the context.

Comment: So if I were to make just one classical component that renders the canvas, would I put all the logic in the componentDidMount? I'm trying to understand where I'd put the 'function Ball()' stuff then.

Comment: Anywhere, you just have to initialize it in the component passing it the canvas

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo aren't arrow functions and bind performing almost with the same speed in the most browsers?

Comment: @VadimKalinin I don't know where that question comes from and it's a really tricky one. To keep it brief, I would assume the browsers native `bind` has better optimizations (the most important one is tail call optimization) than arrow functions. If you're transpiling arrow functions to native functions, which you probably are, then we can safely assume `bind` is much faster, as the transpiler has to do some magic to emulate the lexical `this` of arrow functions. It should be negligible as long as you don't redefine the function unnecessarily, that will re-render child components every time.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo no no, that's not my case, already using arrow functions natively for quite a long time, since the only browser not supporting them is IE.

Actually I managed to find this comment from [one article](https://medium.com/@mharrisonb/hi-what-code-did-you-use-for-your-benchmarks-4feef58ea5ef) where it's actually claimed that `bind` specifically in **Chrome earlier than 59** was even **slower** than arrow functions. And in Firefox it's as well quite a while since they both perform with the same speed.

So I'd say in such cases there is no difference what is the preferred way :)

Comment: Why is necessary to bind the function with the propX? Why not just pass it as argument? <Something onClick={update(props.x, a , b)} /> ?

Comment: @MauricioAvendaño either way works, but it is a bad practice for the `Something` component to know that there is a prop X in its parent component as it makes it aware of its context. The same happens for the question you're asking and the sample code I've written, it depends on the context, which is ignored for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo What does it mean by "Something component to know that there is a prop X in its parent component"? Does it mean that if there is no binding, Something component knows that there is a prop X in its parent component? Could you please elaborate more about this? Is it related to the fact that bind method creates new function?

Comment: @koo to pass `props.x` as an argument to update without using bind would require passing `props.x` to `Something` so it can then pass it to `update` itself, along with `a` and `b`. If we partially apply (pass using bind) `props.x` `Something` doesn't have to know about `props.x` at all.

Comment: You're using bind for the wrong purpose. You should either do `onClick={(a, b) => update(props.x, a, b);}` or declare update as a factory and call it like this: `onClick={update(props.x)}`.

Comment: @fgblomqvist why is partial application a "wrong purpose" of `bind`?

Comment: Because you're using it as a "general-purpose" factory. It's not meant for that, it's meant for binding the "this" object to whatever you pass as the first variable in the function you bind. You should create your own factory instead: `const update = (x) => (a, b) => {};` or whatever the exact syntax is.

Comment: @fgblomqvist I don't agree at all and there is no "factory" involved, its just a partially applied function. I would suggest you to read more on the basics of functional programming.

Comment: What's the performance impact of the function being redefined when re-rendered?

Comment: @Atif Depends on the component and its children.
Understand why: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html
Measure it: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Comment: Quote: *"If you're using hooks, you can use useCallback to ensure the function is only redefined when one of its dependencies (props.x in this case) changes"* -- This is **false**, the function passed to useCallback will get redefined at every render regardless of the dependencies specified. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64328410/7123519

Comment: @SebastianNielsen no, useCallback memoizes the function reference based on the dependencies, as does useMemo. The function will be the same function if the dependencies haven't changed. To check it, make an effect depend on a function memoized by useCallback and you'll see the effect won't run again, that means the function passed is strictly equal to the one passed in the previous render, hence, it is the same reference because funcionts are compared by reference like objects.

Comment: using `callBack()` is not always a good idea. For more reference check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289811/function-inside-functional-component-in-react-hooks-performance

Comment: @ImtiazShakilSiddique memoizing with useCallback has no performance penalty at all and avoids generating a new reference which will prevent unnecessary downstream re-renders. On top of that, if you ever use a function in an effect having it already memoized with useCallback is usefull to keep track of dependency changes. That's why  I would recommend always using useCallback for every function. I've done this thousands of times on different escenarios and I've never found a single one in which not wrapping in useCallback would be better that doing it. The answer you linked is contested.

Comment: thanks @MarcoScabbiolo for the explanation... I think you should also post your comment on that thread.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo it seems like there is direct contention out there re: your statements on whether the first parameter to `useCallback` gets redefined. Both the stack overflow link you posted and this article are contesting your point here. While that reference may be cached for referential  comparison, the reference passed to the function is not somehow cached in the outer scope?

Comment: @Esten There is no absolute consensus. You can use or not use useCallback on a case by case basis, and that will always be the best. What I've said is if you want to avoid the overhead of choice and standarize a specific practice, always using useCallback is by far the best. Of course some will disagree. The first argument to useCallback is a function declaration redefined on each render but the result of useCallback is cached, so it will prevent downstream changes and thus is better suited to pass as a prop or use as a dependency to other hooks.

Answer (score 21):

You can place functions inside stateless functional components:

```js
function Action() {
    function handlePick(){
        alert("test");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="button" onClick={handlePick} value="What you want to do ?" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

But it's not a good practice as the function `handlePick()` will be defined every time the component is rendered.

It would be better to define the function outside the component:

```js
function handlePick(){
    alert("test");
}

function Action() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="button" onClick={handlePick} value="What you want to do ?" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If it's not good practice, how do you write functions inside function components that would've been class methods in a class-style React component?  These methods typically need access to state and so must be inside the function.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to use props or state of a component in a function, that should be defined in the component with `useCallback`.

```js
function Component(props){
  const onClick=useCallback(()=>{
     // Do some things with props or state
  },[])

  return <Something {...{onClick}} />
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to use props or state in a function, define that outside of the component.

```js
const computeSomethings=()=>{
   // Do some things with params or side effects
}

function Component(props){
  return <Something onClick={computeSomethings} />
}
```

For HTML tags you don't need `useCallback` because that will handle in the react side and will not be assigned to HTML.

```js
function Component(props){
  const onClick=()=>{
     // Do some things with props or state
  }

  return <div {...{onClick}} />
}
```

**Edit: Functions in hooks**

For using function in hooks, for example `useEffect`, my suggestion is defining a function inside `useEffect`. If you're worried about DRY, make your function pure call it in hook and give your params to it. What about hooks deps? You should/could add all of your params to hooks deps, but `useEffect` just needs deps which should affect for them changes.

Comment: can you give an example of using hook for method inside functional component? (not set state method)

Answer (score 5):

We can use the React hook `useCallback` as below in a functional component:

```
const home = (props) => {
    const { small, img } = props
    const [currentInd, setCurrentInd] = useState(0);
    const imgArrayLength = img.length - 1;
    useEffect(() => {
        let id = setInterval(() => {
            if (currentInd < imgArrayLength) {
                setCurrentInd(currentInd => currentInd + 1)
            }
            else {
                setCurrentInd(0)
            }
        }, 5000);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
    }, [currentInd]);
    const onLeftClickHandler = useCallback(
        () => {
            if (currentInd === 0) {

            }
            else {
                setCurrentInd(currentInd => currentInd - 1)
            }
        },
        [currentInd],
    );

    const onRightClickHandler = useCallback(
        () => {
            if (currentInd < imgArrayLength) {
                setCurrentInd(currentInd => currentInd + 1)
            }
            else {

            }
        },
        [currentInd],
    );
    return (
        <Wrapper img={img[currentInd]}>
            <LeftSliderArrow className={currentInd > 0 ? "red" : 'no-red'} onClick={onLeftClickHandler}>
                <img src={Icon_dir + "chevron_left_light.png"}></img>
            </LeftSliderArrow>
            <RightSliderArrow className={currentInd < imgArrayLength ? "red" : 'no-red'} onClick={onRightClickHandler}>
                <img src={Icon_dir + "chevron_right_light.png"}></img>
            </RightSliderArrow>
        </Wrapper>);
}

export default home;
```

I'm getting 'img' from it's parent and that is an array.

Comment: Thank you - I had a feeling there was a hook so that we could list dependencies of a `const` function inside of a functional compoenet!

Comment: UseCallback is only useful for memorizing the function, so that on each render the function can be memorized itself, which takes dependencies of a props or state.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const a = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={a}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Example;
```

Comment: I would recommend not answering a question that has been around for 3 years and has an answered question with so many up votes. You probably wont get yours voted on.