# How can we write a click handler for a Stateless Function Component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react application, I have created a stateless Function Component which has a button in the JSX. I want to write a click handler for that button but defining the click handler outside the function throws me error.
I am learning react and I have seen many tutorials that mentions we should try to create more stateless component hence I am following this approach.

Here is how I am doing-
My component-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';

handleClick = () =>{
    alert("Button clicked");
 }


const AccordionComp = (props) => (
    <Accordion>
        <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemTitle>
                <h4>List</h4>
            </AccordionItemTitle>
            <AccordionItemBody>
                <table className="accordionTable">
                    <thead className="row">
                        <th className="col-sm-2">City Name</th>
                        <th className="col-sm-2">Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr className="row">
                            <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent.city}</td>
                            <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent.name}</td>
                            <td className="col-sm-2"><button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button></td>
                        </tr>   
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </AccordionItemBody>
        </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
);

export default  AccordionComp
```

Comment: the handleClick should be in the parent component and passed as props

Comment: I think his problematic is not to pass a parent function but to have a click handler within a stateless component which is fully doable, cf answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the function within your component and then declare your return part:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemTitle,
    AccordionItemBody,
} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/fancy-example.css';
import 'react-accessible-accordion/dist/minimal-example.css';



const AccordionComp = (props) => {

const handleClick = () => {
    alert("Button clicked");
 }

return (
    <Accordion>
        <AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItemTitle>
                <h4>List</h4>
            </AccordionItemTitle>
            <AccordionItemBody>
                <table className="accordionTable">
                    <thead className="row">
                        <th className="col-sm-2">City Name</th>
                        <th className="col-sm-2">Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr className="row">
                            <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent.city}</td>
                            <td className="col-sm-2">{props.propFromParent.name}</td>
                            <td className="col-sm-2"><button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</button></td>
                        </tr>   
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </AccordionItemBody>
        </AccordionItem>
    </Accordion>
    )
};

export default  AccordionComp
```

See also this post for interesting infos : [Functions in stateless components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138145/functions-in-stateless-components)

Answer (score 2):

You handler outside the functional component doesn't havve the right syntax, It should be a function or declared as a const

```
const handleClick = () =>{
    alert("Button clicked");
 }
```

or

```
function handleClick () {
    alert("Button clicked");
 }
```

However ideally in such a scenario, either the handler comes as props from the parent which takes some action when it is triggered or you define your functional Component as Class Component if the action to be taken need not be handled by parent