# How to pass a function as a prop in reactjs components?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I need to define a function in one component and call it in another component, both in the same file.

I can't define both functions in the same component. This pre-requisite involves other complexities of the code.

```
const SchematicEditor = () => {
    return(
        <div>
        <Component />
        <ReactCursorPosition className="editor"
        activationInteractionMouse={INTERACTIONS.CLICK}> 
        <PositionLabel />
        </ReactCursorPosition>
        </div>
    )
}
const PositionLabel = (props) => {
  function createSVG()
  {
    alert(width);
  }
  const {
      elementDimensions: {
        width = 0,
        height = 0
      } = {},
      isActive = false,
      isPositionOutside = false,
      position: {
        x = 0,
        y = 0
      } = {}
    } = props;
    return (
      <div className="window" id = "canvas">
        {x: ${x}}<br />
        {y: ${y}}<br />
        {width:: ${width}}<br />
        {height: ${height}}<br />
        {isActive: ${isActive}}<br />
        {isPositionOutside: ${isPositionOutside ? 'true' : 'false'}}<br />
      </div>
    );
  };

const Component = (props) => {
  return(
  <div className='component'>
      <div className="icons">
          <button onClick={() => props.createSVG()}><a href = "" id = "vsource" className="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light white"><i className="material-icons"><img src={vsource} alt={'v source'}/></i></a></button>
      </div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default SchematicEditor;
```

I get the error `Function not defined`.

Comment: PositionLabel is supposed to return some jsx? createSVG() is part of the PositionLabel. Please add the code where the props are passed to the 'Component' Component.

Comment: @SebinBenjamin i have edited and included the full code

Comment: Quick note: stateless functional components cannot have methods. You can declare the functions outside of the component function and reuse the same reference. When you declare the function inside, every time the component is rendered the function will be redefined unnecessarily. Read the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138145/functions-in-stateless-components

Answer (score 0):

You did pass the function as a prop but without name it so you can refer it inside the compnent.
(props)=>{createSVG: (args)=>{func}}

Comment: inside position label? where do i have to refer it?

Comment: You should create the function under SchematicEditor, so you can pass it as a props like i showed you to both .PositionLabel  and Component

Answer (score 0):

```
const PositionLabel = (props) => {     function createSVG()   {
 alert('yo');   
   }
   return(
   <Component createSVG ={()=>createSVG})
       )
     } 
 const Component = (props) => {       return(   <div
   className='component'>
  <div className="icons">
      <button onClick={()=>props.createSVG}></button>
  </div>   
  </div>) }
```

you need to pass function  as props to your component !