# Make a Table Row redirect to a link when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, semantic-ui, react-router-dom

Having a tabe with multiple rows I want to redirect to other page when it's clicked.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

  <Table.Row
      key={myKey}
      onClick={() => <Redirect to={`/another_page/${myKey}}` />}>
      {emptyFirstHeader && (
        <Table.Cell>
          <Image
           stc={blabla}
          />
        </Table.Cell>
      ...
   <Table.Row>
```

I did it like this but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think your JSX needs to be in an exported function. `export function MyComponent({myKey}) { return (<Table.Row...</Table.Row>); }` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Redirect works with switch and route. You can try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const YourFunctionName = () =>{
    const history = useHistory();
    const redirect = (myKey) =>{
        history.push('/another_page/${myKey}`);
     }
     return(
         <Table.Row
      key={myKey}
      onClick={() => redirect(myKey)}>
      {emptyFirstHeader && (
        <Table.Cell>
          <Image
           stc={blabla}
          />
        </Table.Cell>
      ...
     <Table.Row>
   )
}
```

Comment: I get this error message: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: I don't use react hooks, I don't know why is this happening. Here is the whole file: https://pastebin.com/pKuj6ZbP

Comment: Are you calling this funcitonalities out of function? I mean aren't you writing this inside of a function >? or a class? Share the full code Please

Comment: I posted the whole file in the pastebin link.

Comment: Change  `redirect = myKey => {`  to `const redirect = myKey => {`. It should work

Comment: maybe that's possible in TypeScript but not in JavaScript

Comment: Why its not possible ? :o thats the standard ES6 feature not a feature of TS or JS. Have a look at This>

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138145/functions-in-stateless-components#:~:text=When%20you%20declare%20the%20function,the%20properties%20of%20the%20component.