# Place data and logic inside or outside React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learn react, and I dont understand what is the difference between placing data or function inside or outside function components ?

What is the best practice, and when use the first or second example ?

- Declare in component :

```
import React from 'react'

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const list = ['foo', 'bar']

  function add(foo) {
    return foo + 1
  }

  // other logics...

  return (
    // list...
  )
}
```

- Declare outside the component :

```
import React from 'react'

const list = ['foo', 'bar']

function add(foo) {
  return foo + 1
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
  // other logics...

  return (
    // list...
  )
}
```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is a pure function that is not accessing the component's context, you can just put it outside of the component.

It doesn't matter in that case.

But when you need to use `this` inside the function, it's necessary to define it inside the component.

This post could be helpful too.

[Functions in stateless components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138145/functions-in-stateless-components)

Comment: Thanks, it's the same thing for the variables or constants ? And I can, but what is the best practice ? the fact that both are possible is confusing me

Comment: If the function being used outside of the component is like a helper function that is used in another components too, it will be better to define it in another separated file and use it by importing the function.

Comment: Thank you very much it's ok for me now :) The link you shared is very usefull for understand :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2nd option is a better cause when react re-renders the "SomeComponent", it doesn't have to create foo() again and again.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use class components like state and other methods than declare outside component else inside the component. In inside component call function as **this.functionName**