# Should I apply useCallback/ useMemo for all functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a question that should I apply `useCallback/ useMemo` for all `function/ variable` declarations for all functional components.
As far as I know, `useCallback/ useMemo` makes `function/ variable` declarations are not run again after component update. These functions/ variables are only redefined when their dependency changed. It makes rendering job of React use less effort on redefined something unchanged. It just compares object(s) (dependencies of functions/ variables with useCallback/ useMemo) when these objects changed. I think comparing job is faster than redefining.

Example of using `useCallback` hook:

```
const onOpenEnd = useCallback(() => {
    if (BTSheetRef && BTSheetRef.current) BTSheetRef.current.open()
  }, [BTSheetRef, BTSheetRef.current]);
```

Does I misunderstand anything? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You’re still defining a function with every render when using useCallback and useMemo, those functions just memoize the result of the functions you define within useCallback and useMemo, so that you don’t have to run them very often. Also, when not using useCallback or useMemo and rendering your component for the second time, the original function you defined gets garbage collected (freeing up memory space) and then a new one is created. However with useCallback the original function wont get garbage collected and a new one is created, so you're (slightly) worse-off from a memory perspective.

Because of that, it’s often better to just use a regular function within a react component. Unless the function you’re defining is expensive to run and you want to memoize the results, it makes more sense to not use useMemo or useCallback.

Here’s a really good article explaining this: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: Yeah. I just have read article you shared (It's great). But as far as I know, useCallback will create new function definition on every re-render and garbage collection does not clear so there are multiple instances of function used useCallback existed. Does I know exactly?

Comment: Without using useCallback, every re-render will garbage collect and recreate the inner function you're using within your component. When using useCallback, the second re-render you do will not garbage collect the inner function you're using within your useCallback function, and the inner function you're using in your useCallback method will still be defined again. Then, with your next re-render, the original function used in your useCallback will be still not be garbage collected, the function from your second re-render will be deleted, and a new function will be defined in useCallback.

Comment: So when you're using useCallback, you're basically storing a function in memory two times instead of one time with every re-render. It should really only be used for computationally expensive operations that you don't want to run very often and you'd like their results to be memoized, or if you need referential equality on your functions for some reason.

Comment: I get it. Thank a lot. But why useCallback have to redefine inner function while the memoized one is existed. It makes the new one is redundant.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation Ive gotten. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not for all the function/ variable, it should use for some scenarios

[**useCallback**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

- This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders.

If the child component should not be rendered when the parent gets rendered, then you should have to use this hook, why? since we are passing the same function to the child, child component will not get rendered unnecessarily.

[check some code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ajpxfa)

```
const ChildComponent = React.memo(() => {
  const date = new Date().getTime();
  return (
    <div>
      {date}
    </div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(null);

  //if we use this one child component will rerender only if the dependacies of the useCallback gets changed,
  //when dependancies change rect will return a new function, otherwise it will retun the old function.
  const fn = React.useCallback(() => {
  }, []);

  // if we use below fn as a prop to the child, child will rerender on every rendering of this component.
  //because react will give us a new function on every renderings.
  /* 
    const fn = () => {
    } 
  */

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent fn={fn}/>

      <br />
      <p>changing the numbers means that child component gets rerendered</p>
      <button onClick={() => setTime(new Date().getTime())}>change state</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**useMemo**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

- You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.

Means that if you have to calculate a heavy calculation, then you should relay on this hook, why? just because the calculation is not gonna perform on every rendering.

[check some code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vptnb5)

```
export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(null);

//memorizing result of complex calculations
  const heavyComputedValue = React.useMemo(() => {
    //some heavy calculations
    let val = new Date().getTime();
    for (let a = 0; a < 1000000000; a += 1) {
      val += a;
    }

    return val;
  }, []);

//-------without memorizing results of complex calculations----------//
// enabling this will show you component update gets lagging due to calculation happens every time unnecessarily
/*
  let val = new Date().getTime();
  for (let a = 0; a < 1000000000; a += 1) {
    val += a;
  }
  const heavyComputedValue = val;
  */
//--------------------------------------------------------//

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Time: {time}</p>
      Heavy computed value: {heavyComputedValue}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setTime(new Date().getTime())}>
        change state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get one more question. Does useCallback memoize function by creating new one in memory on every render? So its reference also will be changed after these re-rendering. Does I mistake anything?

Comment: `useCallback` keeps the old function, that is how its preventing child component unwanted rendering

Comment: So reference to this function is the same after re-rendering?

Comment: @QuangKhảiĐàm yes only if you are using `useCallback()`

Comment: I have just read an article about this https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback . After reading that I understand that useCallback will create new function every renders and keep the old one (garbage collection does not clear function used with useCallback). So it affects memory and there are multiple instances of this function (ofc the reference is not the same). Does I mistake anything? Thanks

Comment: @QuangKhảiĐàm interesting post, first i don' think facebook will show up such a memory leak, and secondly if we implement an equality check for the props for a childcomponent then it will give us true when using useCallback, check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v7mvdu

Comment: or Simply look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5ues2w, when you click on btn "render child" then you will see `console.log(temp === fn);` is `false`, because when we call `setChild(.` `useCallback` will return a new fn, otherwise it's returning the same function thats why it's print `true` for  `console.log(temp === fn);` on every other senarios

Comment: Thank. I understand. So useCallback is just helpful for keeping child component inheriting function from parent as a prop from re-rendering.

Comment: That's correct since rendering is the most critical/complex time consuming part, it's good to find the right balance to render the children, so yes use it when you want to prevent the renderings of the children