# React Hooks: function should be defined in function or outside of function?

Tags: reactjs, function, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

When I user react hooks, I am wondering if function should be defined in function or outside of function ?

Could you please let me know the reason as well ? Thank you in advance.

Example ↓

1. function defined inside function

```
const createInitialVal = () => { return "Value"}

export const App = () => {
  const initialVal = createInitialVal()
  const [val, setVal] = useState(initialVal)
}
```

2. function defined outside of funtion

```
export const App = () => {
  const createInitialVal = () => { return "Value"}

  const initialVal = createInitialVal()
  const [val, setVal] = useState(initialVal)
}
```

Comment: Personally, if the function is more of a util function - can and will be used in multiple places, I will put it in a separate file as an util function. Otherwise, if the function needs to access the state/props of the component and is not needed anywhere else, then I will keep it inside of that component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions in stateless components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138145/functions-in-stateless-components)

Comment: It depends, but in your example outside makes sense.  But in your example even creating a function in the first place doesn't really make much sense..

Comment: Either will work but if its declared inside the function, every time ```App``` is re-rendered a new reference to that function is created. Therefore this can be a problem if you're passing the function into a ```useEffect``` dependency array. This is where hooks like ```useCallback``` come in handy