# Converting inline function to normal function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lambda, anonymous-function, inline-functions

I am looking to convert an inline function of the following signature to a non-inline function

```
const onMouseEnter = (itemName: string): void => {
 alert(itemName);
};
```

I tried doing as follows but that doesn't seem to work.

```
function onMouseEnter(itemName: string) {
 alert(itemName);
};
```

Here is my codesandbox where it does not compile using the signature above.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-buck-wt66b?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Seems to work fine to me...

Comment: @jnpdx, hm, don't you see a compile error when uncommenting the line onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter2('title')}

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean -- I assumed you wanted to change `const onMouseEnter` to `function onMouseEnter` as described in your question. You may want to clarify that. You can't pass a function with a parameter like what you're trying to do in the commented line, unless the result in turn returns another function.

Comment: @jnpdx, "unless the result in turn returns another function". Could you tell me what this function looks like? I tried to create a function that returns the lambda but that didn't work.

Comment: `const onMouseEnter2 = (itemName: string) => () => { alert(itemName) };`

Answer (score 1):

I checked your codesandbox and it works for me with a little correction. Just be careful to call the `onMouseEnter2` the same way you call the first one (using the arrow function on the event handler) - Otherwise you are triggering the function each time you render:

```
function onMouseEnter2(itemName: string){
  alert(itemName);
};

const addIcon: IIconProps = { iconName: "Add" };

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CommandButton
      //onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter("title")}
      onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter2('title')}
      iconProps={addIcon}
      text="New item"
      menuProps={menuProps}
    />
  );
}
```

However I'd like to remind you that **it is not good practice** to define function inside a functional component as they'll be defined each time the component is rendered. The following thread is interesting on the subject:

[Where should functions in function components go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138145/where-should-functions-in-function-components-go)

Comment: thanks for the reference!
On the original question, I am looking to see if I can use onMouseEnter2 as a regular function (not inline). Is that possible?

Comment: That's what's in my code. the fact your handler is an inline function is because you pass an argument. If you don't do this you trigger the function on load. If the argument can be obtained from another source and not be passed to the function it could work (from local state from example) but that's another problematic