# How to get specific type from a generic hook?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a generic hook that connects to Firebase/Firestore and returns all items from a given collection. I am trying to get the correct type of returned items by creating an `ICollectionMap` interface specifying their types. This is what I have so far:

```
export const useCollection = <TCollectionMap extends Record<string, any>>(
  collectionName: keyof TCollectionMap
): {
  collection: TCollectionMap[keyof TCollectionMap]
} => {
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState<TCollectionMap[keyof TCollectionMap]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch data from Firebase here
    ...
    const data = ...
    setCollection(data)
  }, [])

  return { collection }
}
```

So then, let's say we have the following types:

```
interface INames { name: string }

interface IAges { age: number }

interface ICollectionMap {
  names: INames[]
  ages: IAges[]
}
```

Now when I use the hook:

```
  const { collection } = useCollection<ICollectionMap>('names')
```

I'd like to see the type of `collection` to be `INames[]`, but TypeScript claims it is `INames[] | IAges[]`. Is there a proper way to handle it with TS?

Comment: try this export const useCollection = <TTCollectionMap extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof TTCollectionMap, V extends TTCollectionMap[K]>(
  collectionName: K
): {
  collection: Extract<TTCollectionMap, Record<K, V>>
} => {
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState<Extract<TTCollectionMap, Record<K, V>>>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch data from Firebase here
    ...
    const data = ...
    setCollection(data)
  }, [])

  return { collection }
}

Comment: You h=should have `<TCollectionMap extends Record<string, any>, TName xetends keyof TCollectionMap>`

Comment: @Lapwood and @Dimava both these solutions work, however, I would have to pass more types when calling `useCallback`, like `useCallback< TCollectionMap, 'names'>('names')`. I'd like to avoid passing the `'names'` twice. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to do in one function like so:

```js
export const useCollection = <TCollectionMap extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof TCollectionMap>(
  collectionName: K
): {
  collection: TCollectionMap[K]
} => null!
const { collection } = useCollection<ICollectionMap, 'names'>('names')
//   ^? collection: INames[]
```

It comes with the express limitation that you have to specify all type parameters. This is a consequence of typescript not yet having [partial type inferencing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).

#### Don't use a generic TCollectionMap (?)

Is there any particular reason you need such an abstract `useCollection` function? Consider the following

```js
export const useICollection = <K extends keyof ICollectionMap>(
  collectionName: K
): {
  collection: ICollectionMap[K]
} => null!
const { collection } = useICollection('names')
//   ^? collection: INames[]
```

However, if this is a non-answer consider the next answer

#### Wrapping your function with another function

To get around the lack of partial type inferencing we can use another way, just wrap your function with another generic function

```js
export const createCollection = <TCollectionMap extends Record<string, any>>() => <K extends keyof TCollectionMap>(
  collectionName: K
): {
  collection: TCollectionMap[K]
} => null!
const useICollection = createCollection<ICollectionMap>()
const { collection } = useICollection('names')
//   ^? collection: INames[]
```

Note that this layer of abstraction is purely used for the sake of implementing our own sort of partial type inferencing.

As a side node: if you do go this route, I recommend creating `createdICollection = createCollection<ICollectionMap>()` outside the React component, some more reading about this can be answered by this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46138370/17954209) to the question: [Where should functions in function components go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46138145/17954209)
In short:

> In most cases you should declare the functions outside the component function so you declare them only once and always reuse the same reference. When you declare the function inside, every time the component is rendered the function will be defined again.

#### [View all Examples on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLXkkm)

Comment: Thanks, @Cody Duong, currying solves the problem but I cannot use hooks inside anymore. I see partial inference is not supported in TS yet. I will probably use currying for now and once partial inference is in TS I will switch to that.