# How to update state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying for a while to get this to work and any method I've come across doesn't seem to work.  I've tried [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_state.asp) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875557/creating-custom-function-in-react-component/34875769) and any others seem to follow the same format.  I can't seem to see whats wrong with my code.  If anyone can find the issue that would really help:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Hamburger extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            click: false
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        if (this.state.click) {
            this.setState({click: false});
        } else {
            this.setState({click: true});
        };
    }
    render() {
        let className = 'hamburger';
        if (this.state.click) {
            className += ' cross';
        }

        return (
            <div
                className={className}
                onclick={this.handleClick}
            >
                <svg
                    viewbox='0 0 100 100'
                    preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet'
                >
                    <line x1='10' x2='90' y1='20' y2='20' id='top'/>
                    <line x1='10' x2='90' y1='50' y2='50' id='mid'/>
                    <line x1='10' x2='90' y1='80' y2='80' id='btm'/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onclick` to `onClick` event handlers always in camelCase

Answer (score 1):

your `onclick` should be `onClick`

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers should be in camel cases. I can see you have defined as onclick instead of onClick.

Change to  `<div className={className} onClick={this.handleClick} >`

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 import React from 'react';

export class Hamburger extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            click: false
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({click: !click});
    }
    render() {
        let className = 'hamburger';
        if (this.state.click) {
            className += ' cross';
        }

        return (
            <div
                className={className}
                onclick={this.handleClick}
            >
                <svg
                    viewbox='0 0 100 100'
                    preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet'
                >
                    <line x1='10' x2='90' y1='20' y2='20' id='top'/>
                    <line x1='10' x2='90' y1='50' y2='50' id='mid'/>
                    <line x1='10' x2='90' y1='80' y2='80' id='btm'/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a really good option but unfortunately it needs to change other things at the same time so I need the flip-flop style if statement