# React: 'this.state' is undefined inside a component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble accessing `this.state` in functions inside my component. I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function) question on SO and added the suggested code to my constructor:

```
class Game extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    ...
    this.state = {uid: '', currentTable : '', currentRound : 10, deck : sortedDeck};
    this.dealNewHand = this.dealNewHand.bind(this);
    this.getCardsForRound = this.getCardsForRound.bind(this);
    this.shuffle = this.shuffle.bind(this);
  }

  // error thrown in this function
  dealNewHand(){
    var allCardsForThisRound = this.getCardsForRound(this.state.currentRound); 
  }

  getCardsForRound(cardsPerPerson){
    var shuffledDeck = this.shuffle(sortedDeck);
    var cardsForThisRound = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < cardsPerPerson * 4; i++){
      cardsForThisRound.push(shuffledDeck[i]);
    }
    return cardsForThisRound;
  }

  shuffle(array) {
    ...
  }

  ...
  ...
```

It still does not work. `this.state.currentRound` is undefined. What is the problem?

Comment: cant really tell whats going on from this, it looks fine. Can you upload this into a js fiddle?

Comment: I dont know how to do that with react code.

Comment: base fiddle for es6 and react: https://jsfiddle.net/jhonvolkd/nrd015dm/

Comment: Can't make it work, sorry, thanks anyway

Comment: Nothing happened when I pressed 'run'. 
I edited the question with my full component anyway

Comment: ok there we go, this is an async prob, I'm sure you'll get an answer soon now

Comment: A couple recommendations: 1) Use fat arrow functions (`() => `) instead of `function` and `self`. 2) Don't mutate state (`newState = this.state; newState.currentRount = gameData.currentRound; this.setState(newState)`, instead pass state changes as `setState({currentRound: gameData.currentRound})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came up with something that worked. I changed the code for binding `getCardsForRound` in the constructor to:

```
this.getCardsForRound = this.getCardsForRound.bind(this, this.state.currentRound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your functions this way:

```
dealNewHand = () => {
    var allCardsForThisRound = 
    this.getCardsForRound(this.state.currentRound);
}
getCardsForRound = (cardsPerPerson) => {
    var shuffledDeck = this.shuffle(sortedDeck);
    var cardsForThisRound = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < cardsPerPerson * 4; i++){
        cardsForThisRound.push(shuffledDeck[i]);
    }
    return cardsForThisRound;
}
```

http://www.react.express/fat_arrow_functions

> the binding for the keyword this is the same outside and inside the fat arrow function. This is different than functions declared with function, which can bind this to another object upon invocation. Maintaining the this binding is very convenient for operations like mapping: this.items.map(x => this.doSomethingWith(x)).