# Is there a better way to bind 'this' in React Component classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I am currently working on a react app, and I found having to bind `this` a bit cumbersome when a component class has many functions.

### Example

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.function1 = this.function1.bind(this);
    this.function2 = this.function2.bind(this);
    this.function3 = this.function3.bind(this);
  }
  function1() {
    ...
  }
  function2() {
    ...
  }
  function3() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: how are the functions being used?

Comment: You can also bind it in-line as mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33973745/465053) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41867339/465053) post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid having to bind methods by using the [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) Babel plugin, which is an experimental ES7 feature. Make sure you enable [stage-0](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) in order to use it.

This allows the use of arrow functions when defining your class methods, leveraging arrow functions' lexical binding so `this` refers to function's context (in this case the class), like so:

```
class Foo extends Component {
    boundFunction = () => { /* 'this' points to Foo */ }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm sorely mistaken, this is fixing a different problem. See my answer below.

Comment: @J__ see my comment on your answer. In the case of React components, op is correct. I have submitted an edit to make the question specific to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it a bit with:

this.function1 = ::this.function1

You'll need https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/