# React - Why is binding this not required in this example?

Tags: reactjs, binding

Trying to figure out the basics of React.

Looking at the second example on this page: https://facebook.github.io/react/
I see that the tick() function sets the state of the Timer class, incrementing the previous value by one.

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {secondsElapsed: 0};
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      secondsElapsed: prevState.secondsElapsed + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

However, when I tried to implement my own simple Counter class, it failed and I got a console error saying **Cannot read property setState of undefined.**

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: 0};
    }

    increment(prevState) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            count: prevState.count + 1
        }));
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <div className="main">
                <button onClick={this.increment}>{this.state.count}</button>
            </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Some Googling reveals that I have to bind this to the increment function. But why was that not required in the first example that I saw? I copied the code to CodePen and it ran fine with React 15.3.1 I cannot find anything resembling binding in that example. Only after I added binding code in the constructor did things start working in my example.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: 0};

        // THIS ONE LINE FIXED THE ISSUE
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    }

    increment(prevState) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <div className="main">
                <button onClick={this.increment}>{this.state.count}</button>
            </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Answering your question: the first example uses `arrow functions`, that automatically performs [context binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this). From the docs:

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has
>   its original meaning from the enclosing context.

Indeed there are some ways of binding in React:

1) you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) all functions in your constructor, like you said:

```
constructor(props) {
    /* ... */
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
}
```

2) invoke your callbacks with arrow functions:

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.increment(e)}>
```

3) append [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) at the end of your method reference each time you set it as a callback, like this:

```
<button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>
```

4) In your class, define the method with arrow functions:

```
increment = (e) => {
  /* your class function defined as ES6 arrow function */
}

/* ... */

<button onClick={this.increment}>
```

In order to use this syntax with babel, you have to enable this [plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) or use [stage-2](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) preset.

Comment: So, based on what I have read, if I call this.increment() without use of an arrow function, 'this' gets bound to the global object. Is that correct?


I also realized I put the callback as {this.increment} instead of {this.increment()}. If I add the parentheses to the callback, the explicit binding in the constructor no longer fixes the problem. Furthermore, the value of state hits a large number then goes no higher. I think its because its being called repeatedly?


I have a solution now but I just want to understand exactly the cause of the issue to further my understanding.

Comment: *I also realized I put the callback as {this.increment} instead of {this.increment()}* You should not put the parentheses. You have to pass just the reference: if you put the parentheses, you'll be calling the method, and pass the return to the brackets.

Comment: If I might, I suggest reading [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes). And you can check the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) reference too.

Comment: Alright I've got some reading ahead of me.
In regards to all of the methods mentioned for binding this and making a callback, are there any which are preferable? I asked a colleague and he said that using the _this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);_ in the constructor makes the most sense since you won't be calling it over and over when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Nephelus I think it's a matter of personal taste, but also depends on your code organization, and how many events do you have. But I suggest to adopt a standard in your project (do it in the same way or all over the files). I, personally, prefer the constructor way for the exact reasons you mentioned. Good luck in your project.

Comment: For sure all four ways help us to bind the `this` instance correctly but are all four ways absolutely the same in usage? I mean, shall I prefer any one of them over the others or all are exactly the same without any side-effects or disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the way the `tick()` function has been called in your fist example, you will understand that binding has been specified to it when it is called using the `arrow functions`. If you do the same for the increment function it will also work. These are just different ways of binding the functions.

So as asked, its not that in the first example no binding is specified while the second it requires, rather in both your cases you are binding just that the way of binding is different for  both the cases.

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count: 0};

        
       
    }

    increment(prevState) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1
    }));
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <div className="main">
                <button onClick={() => this.increment()}>{this.state.count}</button>
            </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```