# React Native - onRefresh component triggering refresh with bind(this) vs invoking a func regularly?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, react-native

Im using the React Native (version 0.46) RefreshControl component to update my ListView.

I stumbled upon a difference in the way the triggering happens in two separate documentations:

A) React native documentation shows that triggering the RefreshControl component happens when the user pulls to refresh and the **onRefresh** gets triggered. In their example they trigger onRefresh with this line
 [onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html#usage-example)

They use this._onRefresh.bind(this) and if im not mistaken, what this is generally doing (without diving into details) making sure that we are invoking the **_onRefresh** function from the global scope.

B) I found this documentation showing that I could invoke the triggering like so:

**`onRefresh={()=>this._refreshListView()}`**

Note: this is from Stackoverflow's documentation, and for those who object to SOF's doc, im just interested in the difference between those lines of code.

**My Question:** is there significant difference between the two? (feel free to be meticulous). Also, is my understanding of what **bind** is doing correct given what i described above? if not, is there a reason for choosing one way over the other ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, *this* is probably the element youre in.

And the main difference between *bind* and *arrow functions* is, that bind creates  a bound function, that calls the regular function bind was called on with a certain context when called, while arrow functions dont have their own context at all, making them a bit more lightweight. However, thats unmeasurable.

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867259/react-why-is-binding-this-not-required-in-this-example)

Comment: i checked the perf monitor using the expo app, and you are correct, the difference is unmeasurable. do you mind elaborating on what do you mean by " that calls the regular function with a certain context" what is that context ?

Comment: @user3676224 the first argument of bind?

Comment: Yes, so the function gets called as follows: this.o_onRefresh.bind(this). I dont quite understand what happens when passing "this" to reference the context. I would appreciate any explanation regarding that part.

Comment: @user3676224 it returns a new function ( a bound function ) that calls the original function with that context