# How does bind work inside react classes and JSX events ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying here to understand the necessity of the binding I commented ..

```
class Toggle extends Component {

    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    //this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}


handleClick() {

    console.log(this); 

}


render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            ...
        </button>
    );
}

}
```

when I log `this` inside the `handleClick` it outputs `null` ..

I understand that the binding is needed to connect the `handleClick` method to the `Toggle` Object ..

But shouldn't the log now look for where was the `handleClick` invoked or called so it would output global object ?

Or should it  have looked for 'what' invoked the `handleClick` inside the `onClick` which is the other `this` that refer there to the `Toggle` Object so it would output it ?

Comment: `this` will only refer to the global object if the function is *not* **strict**. Classes are always strict. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 1):

If you bind `handleClick` in `Toggle`, it will indeed bind the method to the class as shown below, when I tried to log the value property in the state. It will throw an error otherwise and you can check it in your browser console (NOT in the code snippet one).

I'm not 100% sure why console.log(this) in unbinded `handleClick` (The OP of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function) had similar problem) returns undefined, but my guess that it could be that it is referring to a null component, as it has `undefined` for its `this` value.

```js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 'hi' }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.state.value); 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Hello
        </button>
        <NullComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let NullComponent = () => { 
  console.log('calling from null component ', this);
  return null; 
}

ReactDOM.render(<Toggle />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```