# in react inside a Component , why we require to use "this." to give reference to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

```
class First extends React.Component{
    handleClick(){
        alert('handle click');
    } 

    render(){
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
        </div>;
    }
 }
```

in above example why we need to use **this.handleClick** instead of just **handleclick**

when this is not used

> 'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef

an indepth explanation is appreciated

Comment: You also need to add a binding: `... onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`. Otherwise `this` value inside the `handleClick` method will have an unexpected value when you click the button. You can find more information about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a React thing. It's a JavaScript thing.

Without `this.`, `handleClick` is an identifier reference, and that means you have to have an in-scope declared variable with the name `handleClick`. You don't have that. You have a *property* on the component instance called `handleClick`, but that's not in scope anywhere.

It's the same reason you need `this` here:

```js
class Example {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  showValue() {
    console.log(this.value); // <== Works
  }
  
  brokenShowValue() {
    console.log(value);      // <== ReferenceError, `value` is not defined
  }
}
const e = new Example(42);
e.showValue();
e.brokenShowValue();
```

There *are* languages which allow `this.` to be implicit (such as Java and C#), but JavaScript does not.

---

Side note: If at some point you use `this` in `handleClick` (you don't currently), be sure to read [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function). You'll need to do something to ensure that the correct `this` is available within the call (your code doesn't do that at the moment).

Comment: It di s not fix the issue

Comment: @AlexanderElgin - Read the question again, please. This isn't about `this` within `handleClick`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in JavaScript class properties and methods are not available directly by their name:

```
class Foo {
    bar() {}
    test() {
        bar(); // Error: undefined function
    }
}
```

When you call `bar()` in the example above, JavaScript tries to find the function called `bar` in the global namespace.

You need to type `this.` explicitly to access a current object property or method:

```
class Foo {
    bar() {}
    test() {
        this.bar(); // OK
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of function in global namespace  as :-" JavaScript tries to find the function called bar in the global namespace." @Finesse

Comment: @SanjaySinghBhandari `function bar() { console.log(1) } class Foo { bar() { console.log(2) } test() { bar(/* logs "1" */); this.bar(/* logs "2" */); } }`