# When accessing props of a component "this" is unedefined after mapping state to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

While using react-redux and mapping state to props with connect() the received state has the correct values but when accessing the variables through this.props "this" is always undefined.

When pressing the button (in there for test purposes only) on the sidebar component the second console log always fails with TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined  on console.log(this.props.visibility).

Am i missing something extra that is needed in order to allow access of the newly maped values in mapStateToProps through this.props ? or even if i should be accessing them in another way other then this.props.

Thanks in advance.

The component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {toggleSidebarVisibility } from '../../actions/layoutActions';


class Sidebar extends Component{

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <button class='btn btn-secondary' onClick={test}>B</button>
        </div>      
      );        
    }
}

function test(){
  console.log("hello");
  console.log(this.props.visibility)

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  console.log(state.layout.sidebarVisibility);
  return {
    visibility: state.layout.sidebarVisibility,
  }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Sidebar from './components/layout/Sidebar';
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import store from './store';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store ={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Sidebar/>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {

};

const middleWare = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer,initialState,compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleWare),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    ));

export default store;
```

RootReducer

```
import {combineReducers } from 'redux';
import layoutReducer from './layoutReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    layout : layoutReducer
});
```

LayoutReduccer

```
import {TOGGLE_SIDEBAR_VIS} from '../actions/types';

const initialState  = {
    sidebarVisibility : true
}

export default function(state = initialState,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case TOGGLE_SIDEBAR_VIS:
            return{ ...state,sidebarVisibility:action.payload};   
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the context of the `test` function, you can do that using something like this: `onClick={test.bind(this)}`

Comment: use an arrow function for test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: "this" is undefined inside a component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write functions inside class/statefull component they no need function keyword before function name. So test function can be written as test(){ or arrow function test = () => {

The reason this is undefined inside function in your case because function needs binding in order to access this and state or props. Either you need to manually bind the function in constructor or change it to arrow function like I did below

Approach 1:

Manually bind the function in constructor

```
      constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.test = this.test.bind(this);
       }

       test = () => {
          console.log("hello");
          console.log(this.props.visibility);
      }
```

OR

Approach2:

You can change test function to arrow function hence manual binding in constructor isn’t required because arrow functions takes binding automatically thus this is available inside arrow function

Change

```
function test(){
  console.log("hello");
  console.log(this.props.visibility);
}
```

To

```
test = () => {
  console.log("hello");
  console.log(this.props.visibility);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was so firmly conviced it was something i was doing wrong on the react-redux side of things that i forgot to check the basics such as scoping.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [`JavaScript#lexical scoping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

One need to bind to component `this` using `.bind` or [`JavaScript#arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

**Sol1 :** Using [`JavaScript#arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```
test = () => {
  console.log("hello");
  console.log(this.props.visibility)

}
```

**Sol2:** Using explicit this binding using [`JavaScript#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

inside constructor:

```
constructor(){

  this.test = this.test.bind(this);
}


test(){
  //code
}
```