# function declaration vs lambda (in react?)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I’m doing a TO-DO list tutorial in react and it was failing because I wrote something like this:

```
class TodoItems extends Component {
  createTasks(item) { // define it as a function
      // using “this” here breaks the app
      ...

   }
}
```

And the correct way to do it is

```
class TodoItems extends Component {
    createTask = (item) => { // using a lambda 
       // using this here is ok
       ...
     }
}
```

Example source code: https://github.com/therj/react-todo
(specifically [here](https://github.com/therj/react-todo/blob/master/src/TodoItems.js#L4))

Why is `this` undefined in the first one?

I tried to declare the class using the node interpreter but the prompt never returns

```
> class A {}
undefined
> class TodoItems /*extends Component*/ {
...     createTasks= (item) => {
.....         return (
.......             <li key={item.key} onClick={() => this.props.deleteItem(item.key)}>
.......                 {item.text}
.......
...             </li>
...         )
...     }
...
...     render() {
...         const todoEntries = this.props.entries
...         const listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks)
...         return <ul className="theList">{listItems}</ul>
...     }
... }
...
...
>
(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
```

Not sure if this is react related, es6, or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: "this" is undefined inside a component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function)

Comment: @UncleDave that's totally the reason. Thanks.