# this in a function inside render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know [how to handle `this` inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function), but in my case none of those solutions works and I still get

> this is undefined

The problem is I have a function inside `render()` method and I dont know how to handle it.

This is a part of my code

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         //states
    }
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
  }

changePage (event) {
   // some codes
}

 render() {
     function PrevPage() {
      return (
        <li key="p-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
          <a href="#">&lt;</a>
        </li>
      )
     }
    return (
         <div>
           <PrevPage />
            ...
         </div>
     )
 }
}
```

I get the error at this line

```
<li key="n-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
```

I tried putting this line in constructor:

```
 this.PrevPage= this.PrevPage.bind(this);
```

but `PrevPage` is not recognized by this.

Also if i convert `PervPage` to arrow function:

```
PrevPage = () => {
  return (
    <li key="p-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
      <a href="#">&lt;</a>
    </li>
  )
}
```

I get this error:

> 'PrevPage' is not defined  no-undef

I know I'm missing somthing but I cant figure out what

Comment: the problem with using <PrevPage /> is that it is not a react component. it's a simple function local to render hence use JSX Expression {PrevPage()} and it will return you the JSX you have returned.

Comment: *"'PrevPage' is not defined no-undef"* You have to use `const`, `let` or `var` when you declare a variable. Then it will work.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right. I wouldv'e fix the issue before I ask the question If I haven't missed a 'const' before the arrow function. But asking this question and looking at the answer taught me new things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just remove the function outside the render? Generally speaking you want to keep the `render` logic as clean as possible and your PrevPage component can really just be a normal method. Seems kind of superfluous to define a child-component within render, and then return it immediately.

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         //states
    }
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
    this.prevPage = this.prevPage.bind(this);
  }

changePage (event) {
   // some codes
}

prevPage() {
   return (
     <li key="p-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
        <a href="#">&lt;</a>
     </li>
   )
}

 render() {
    return (
         <div>
            {this.prevPage()}
            ...
         </div>
     )
 }
}
```

Or if you want, just create a brand-new component for `PrevPage`, and pass down the `changePage` handler as props. The `changeHandler` will still be bound to the `Pagination` component context.

**PrevPage.js**

```
const PrevPage = (props) => {
   return (
     <li key="p-page" onClick={props.changePage}>
        <a href="#">&lt;</a>
     </li>
   )
}

export default PrevPage
```

**Pagination.js**

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         //states
    }
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
  }

changePage (event) {
   // some codes
}

 render() {
    return (
         <div>
            <PrevPage changePage={this.changePage}/>
         </div>
     )
 }
}
```

Comment: There are many great solutions for my answer here. I just tried yours and it worked. Thanks to you and everyone else. Also I wanted to do it before I ask, but I didn't know how to call it in render.

Comment: Definitely, this was very well-received question. :). Thanks for accepting mine and thanks for asking! I also learned something from this experience!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. bind `PrevPage` inside `render`:

   ```
   render() {
        function PrevPage() {
         return (
           <li key="p-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
             <a href="#">&lt;</a>
           </li>
         )
        }
        PrevPage = PrevPage.bind(this);
       return (
            <div>
              <PrevPage />
               ...
            </div>
        )
    }
   }
   ```
2. Save `this` in a different variable:

   ```
   render() {
       const that = this;
        function PrevPage() {
         return (
           <li key="p-page" onClick={that.changePage}>
             <a href="#">&lt;</a>
           </li>
         )
        }
       return (
            <div>
              <PrevPage />
               ...
            </div>
        )
    }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind you function to contructor and call the function on your **li tag** as an arrow function and also put your **PrevPage function** outside **render function** like this:

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         //states
    }
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
    this.PrevPage = this.PrevPage.bind(this);
  }

changePage (event) {
// some codes
}

PrevPage() {
    return (
        <li key="p-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
        <a href="#">&lt;</a>
        </li>
    )
}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
        { this.PrevPage() }
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript syntax. You cannot put a function definition like this indie the class body.

Comment: Yes you are right it was a typo forgot to change it

Comment: `onClick={() => this.changePage()}` is still wrong though. Either use what the OP uses or pass the event object to `changePage`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PrevPage` should be a separate component. It is not a good pattern to define a new component in the render function.

You can define it as a function component:

```
const PrevPage => (props) {
    return (
        <li key="p-page" onClick={props.onChangePage}>
            <a href="#">&lt;</a>
        </li>
    )
}

class Pagination extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //states
        }
        this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
    }

    changePage (event) {
        // some codes
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PrevPage onChangePage={this.changePage}/>
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've defined is a private function inside `render` method, therefore your attempt to bind it in the constructor not works, you have 2 choices:

1. Convert `PrevPage` function to arrow-function.

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //states
    };
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
  }

  changePage(event) {
    // some codes
  }

  render() {
    const PrevPage = () => {
      return (
        <li key="p-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
          <a href="#">&lt;</a>
        </li>
      );
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <PrevPage />
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2. Make `PrevPage` function as a class method, and then bind it in the constructor as you did - this method will preform better, cause you won't make a closure each time `render` method is called.

```
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //states
    };
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
    this.renderPrevPage = this.renderPrevPage.bind(this);
  }

  changePage(event) {
    // some codes
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderPrevPage()}
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderPrevPage() {
    return (
      <li key="p-page" onClick={this.changePage}>
        <a href="#">&lt;</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code.

1. You are creating a function PrevPage in render method and calling it as a component instead you have to call it as a function.
2. You are not binding the method changePage correctly to OnClick.

   This is how I will write this code.

   ```
   render() {
    function PrevPage() {
     return (
       <li key="p-page" onClick={ () => this.changePage }>
         <a href="#">&lt;</a>
       </li>
     )
    }
   return (
        <div>
          {PrevPage()}
           ...
        </div>
    )
   ```

I will suggest you to write PrevPage function outside the render method and call it like this.

{this.PrevPage}

Hope it helps you.

Comment: *"You are creating a function PrevPage in render method and calling it as a component instead you have to call it as a function. "* That's not true. Components can be classes or functions.

Comment: if defined outside render then `{this.PrevPage()}`, use `()` since you want it to run imediately and return jsx, otherwise it will not run and no jsx returned.

Comment: *"You are not binding the method changePage correctly to OnClick."* The OP does is right. It's incorrect in your code. It should be `onclick={(e) => this.changePage(e)}` which is exactly the same as `onclick={this.changePage}`. In other words, the two issues you are pointing out are not issues at all.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
<li key="n-page" onClick={() => this.changePage()}>
```

Comment: Why do you think this would solve the problem? This is already wrong because `changePage` is not passed the event object it expects.

Answer (score -1):

change it to arrow function to get "this" instance like in below code,

```
changePage = (event) => {
   /* here you can access to "this" instance
   eg: this.setState({ pageName:'myPage' )}
  */
}
```

Comment: `changePage` is not part of the problem. OP already binds it correctly in the constructor.