# can't use a member function inside fetch call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I get a response from a fetch call and i'm trying to check if the respond correspond to a kind of error my server is likely to respond me if the username or the email sent already exist in my database. If this is the case, i try to use a member function of my class to show a error message to the user. But when i try to use my member function i get the error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'showValidationErr' of undefined.

I think that i can't use a member function in that case, how can i call my member function when i catch a error from my server ?

```
class RegisterBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      errors: [],
      pwdState: null};
    }

    showValidationErr(elm, msg) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ( {errors: [...prevState.errors, {elm, msg} ] } ) );
    }

    submitRegister(e) {
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/register?user=" + this.state.username + "&psw=" + this.state.password + "&email=" + this.state.email)
            .then(function (respond) {
              return respond.text()
              .then(function(text) {
                if (text === "RegisterError : username") {
                  this.showValidationErr("username", "username allready taken.");
                }
                if (text === "RegisterError : email") {
                  this.showValidationErr("email", "email allready used.");
                }
              })
            });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33973745/1815231

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: "this" is undefined inside a component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function)

Comment: Use arrow function for the promise resolve callback.

Comment: `.then` should use arrow functions so `this` can refer to the `RegisterBox` component.

Answer (score 1):

I found how to correct it. i needed to add the line "var that = this;" at the beginning of my function and use "that.showValidationErr();" instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `this` refers to the anonymous callback `function()` that you're passing to the `then()`. Try using the arrow function syntax instead which keeps the `this` as the surrounding context.

```js
        .then((respond) => {
          return respond.text()
          .then((text) => {
            if (text === "RegisterError : username") {
              this.showValidationErr("username", "username allready taken.");
            }
            if (text === "RegisterError : email") {
              this.showValidationErr("email", "email allready used.");
            }
          })
```