# What is the correct way to set state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Honestly, this is my day 1 in ReactJS. I'm learning some small-small things like `state`. I've created a small program for the toggle button. It will simply display "Hello world!" or display nothing when the button is toggled. There's one thing that I didn't understand. My code gives me an error when I use this syntax:

```
  toggleHandler() {
    const currentStatus=this.state.display;
    this.setState({
      display: !currentStatus
    })
  }
```

> this.state is undefined

But the same code works perfectly If I change the syntax to a fat arrow function:

```
  toggleHandler=()=> {
    const currentStatus=this.state.display;
    this.setState({
      display: !currentStatus
    })
  }
```

I'll not waste your time. I've created an [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sszv9t). Experts on the internet say that any call to `this.setState()` is asynchronous. So I tried using `call back function` and `IIFE` but got myself more confused and over-complicated. Please correct me. I'm sorry this is a very childish question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function i think this would help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There are a couple of ways.**

One is to add in the constructor. **ES6 React.Component doesn't auto bind methods to itself**. You need to bind them yourself in constructor. Like this

`this.toggleHandler = this.toggleHandler.bind(this);`

Another is arrow functions `toggleHandler = (event) => {...}.`

And then there is `onClick={this.toggleHandler.bind(this)}`

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33973745/8425297)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any setState call is asynchronous. You can check your log that it changes his status but not manipulate the dom. For manipulating the dom Any asynchronous call should be via a callback function.

you can bind any state with this arrow function or this.state.bind(this).

Answer (score 1):

What the error message is telling you is that the `this` object doesn't contain a property called `state`. What exactly `this` refers to is a constant source of confusion in JS, except when inside an arrow function. Inside an arrow function, `this` always refers to the context the arrow function appears in.

The issue here is in the first example, `this` refers to the context sent to the handler by the onClick event. This context does not contain a `state` property. However, inside the arrow function, the `this` keyword will refer to the JavaScript class that your arrow function exists in. This class *does* have the `state` property.

To get around this, you can use `bind` (which outputs a copy of your function with the context set to whatever you supply it with. Or just use arrow functions. If it were me I would take the latter approach since `this` has better defined and more consistent behaviour inside an arrow function. If you do want to use `bind`, you would do this in your event handler declaration like so:

`onClick={this.toggleHandler.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 1):

The way you can use functions and previous state.

1- Binding in constructor

```
constructor() {
    this.toggleHandler=this.toggleHandler.bind(this);
  }
```

can define like this

```
  toggleHandler=()=>{
    this.setState(prev=>({
      display: !prev.display
    }))
  }
```

2- arrow function (don't need to bind in constructor)

```
  toggleHandler=()=>{
    this.setState(prev=>({
      display: !prev.display
    }))
  }
```

3- Inline binding

```
<Button onClick={this.toggleHandler.bind(this)}>Toggle</Button>
```

function code

```
  toggleHandler=()=>{
    this.setState(prev=>({
      display: !prev.display
    }))
  }
```

4- Inline arrow function

```
 <Button onClick={()=>this.toggleHandler()}>Toggle</Button>
```

function code

```
  toggleHandler=()=>{
    this.setState(prev=>({
      display: !prev.display
    }))
  }
```

> Note - Recommended to avoid inline functions for better performance