# Getting error of "Cannot read props of undefined" when being passed to child component for onChange method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, react-props

I'm getting an error of "Cannot read props of undefined" when passing an onchange function to a child component, however, when console logging the props, the correct properties show up.

I did this previously where I passed an onClick prop to a child button, and that seems to have worked fine.

The error message only happens when attempting to edit the field.

[Console logged props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0QYb.png)

Parent component

```js
//Parent component
  onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <div className="cardRow">             
              <Card question={this.state.currentCard.question} 
                    answer={this.state.currentCard.answer} 
                    source={this.state.currentCard.source}
                    onClick={this.submitUpdate.bind(this)}
                    recordChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}>{this.state.update}</Card>  
                .....
                
  //child component
  class Card extends Component {
    
    //the below code is where the error message is pointing
    recordChange(){
        this.props.recordChange();
    }

    onSubmit(){
        this.props.onSubmit();
    }

    render(props){
        console.log(this.props);
        return(
            <div className="card-container">
                    {this.props.children? 
                        <div className="cardUpdate"> 
                            <form className="update-form">
                                <h5>Front</h5>
                                    <input  type="text"
                                            value={this.props.question}
                                            onChange={this.recordChange}/>
                                <h5>Answer</h5>
                                <textarea  type="text"
                                            value={this.props.answer}
                                            onChange={this.recordChange}/>
                                <h5>Source</h5>
                                <input  type="text"
                                            value={this.props.source}
                                            onChange={this.recordChange}/>
                                <div>
                                    <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Submit</button>    
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>        
                        :
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="front">
                                    <div className="question">{this.props.question}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="back">
                                    <div className="answer">{this.props.answer}</div>
                                    <div className="source">{this.props.source}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    }      
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: "this" is undefined inside a component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recordChange` does not have access to `this` as being in the context of the class.

```js
recordChange() {
  // 'this' is undefined.
  this.props.recordChange();
}
```

However, as you noticed, `console.log(this.props);` inside `render` works fine. This is because `render` is called within the context of the class; whereas `recordChange` is not.

Change it to an arrow function so that `this` is in scope:

```js
recordChange = () => {
  this.props.recordChange();
}
```

Or bind it to `this` in the constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.recordChange = this.recordChange.bind(this);
}

recordChange(){
  this.props.recordChange();
}
```

Or better yet:

Don't use the child function at all. If all it does is call the function from `props` it is unnecessary. Just do `onChange={this.props.recordChange}`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! this worked. I ended up going with the last portion and passing the props directly to the onChange prop.