# How can I update this.state with a method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set new values to a state, but I can't do this with the methods, the state stills the same.

here a declare my state

```
 this.state = {
    notes: [],
    selected: null
    };
}
```

using componentDidMount I can update the state

```
  componentDidMount() {
this.setState({
  notes: this.service.notes,
  selected: {
       title: "vazio",
       text: "vazio"
     }
    });
  }
```

but when I use this methods to update, the state stills the same

```
  onSelect(note) {
   this.setState({
   selected: note
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to call the onSelect method from it's own context by using my for example a lambda, like onSelect="()=> onSelect()". Problem here is the contract where "this" is referring to. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Yes, it's binding to my note that i'm passing in other component, do u know how can I update the state with that note?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function

Comment: Are you getting any erors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
onSelect = note => {
  this.setState({
  selected: note
 });
}
```

This gives the onSelect property access to the component scope

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
onSelect = (note) => () => {
   this.setState({
      selected: note
   })
}
```

It builds a callback function, providing `note` as an argument

Use it as follows

`onSelect={onSelect(note)}`

On whatever handler you are using