# React input field onKeyPress problem of calling other function

Tags: reactjs

```
class A extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      this.sendMsg = this.sendMsg.bind(this)
   }

   sendMsg(){
     console.log("Message is send!!!")
   }

keyPressed(event){
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.sendMsg()
    }
}

render(){
   return(
      <input 
          type="text" 
          className="form-control input-chat border-0" 
          id="inputMessage" 
          placeholder="Type a new message" 
          onKeyPress={this.keyPressed}
      />
   )
}
```

}

Error: `this.sendMsg()` is undefined.

The above code show a component of input box, if the user click enter, I would like to display a console message. But there have a problem occur as above.
What need to be added to the code to run it properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function

Comment: You need to bind keyPressed as well, because `this` is `undefined` in the method body. And thus you are accessing from `undefiend.sendMsg()`

Comment: you are missing the ```super(props)``` and bind keyPressed or use arraow functions https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-bush-cj8rq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `keyPressed` function too.

```
class A extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.sendMsg = this.sendMsg.bind(this)
 this.keyPressed = this.keyPressed.bind(this)
}

sendMsg(){
 console.log("Message is send!!!")
}

keyPressed(event){
if (event.key === "Enter") {
    this.sendMsg()
}
}

render(){


return(
      <input 
          type="text" 
          className="form-control input-chat border-0" 
          id="inputMessage" 
          placeholder="Type a new message" 
          onKeyPress={this.keyPressed}
      />
   )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the parent contructor in your component, which means you can't use `this` until after you’ve called the parent constructor.

[image: constructor]

Add `super(props)`to your constructor to call the parent constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.sendMsg = this.sendMsg.bind(this);
}
```

You also need to bind the keyPressed function as `this` inside keyPressed points to a different thing or use arrow functions instead.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.sendMsg = this.sendMsg.bind(this);
  this.keyPressed = this.keyPressed.bind(this);
}
```

Using arrow functions

```
export default class A extends React.Component {

  sendMsg = () => {
    console.log("Message is send!!!");
  }

  keyPressed = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.sendMsg();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control input-chat border-0"
        id="inputMessage"
        placeholder="Type a new message"
        onKeyPress={this.keyPressed}
      />
    );
  }
}
```