# Cannot convert hooks code to a class in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am currently trying to write a class from the example I saw that uses hooks, however, I am can't make things work. Can someone help me with this? Here's the code. It's adding a field dynamically in React. The error says:
./src/App.js
Line 27:34:  'handleInputChange' is not defined  no-undef
Line 34:34:  'handleInputChange' is not defined  no-undef
Line 38:36:  'handleAddClick' is not defined     no-undef

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

     this.state = {
      inputList: [{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]
    };

    this.handleAddClick = this.handleAddClick.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  // handle input change
   handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
   const list = [...this.state.inputList];
   list[index][name] = value;
   this.setState({ inputList: list });
 }


  // handle click event of the Add button
  handleAddClick = () => {
    this.setState({
     inputList: [...this.state.inputList, { firstName: '', lastName: '' }]
    });
  }

 render() {
 return (
  <div className="App" >
    {
      this.state.inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="box">
            <input
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="Enter First Name"
              value={x.firstName}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />
            <input
              className="ml10"
              name="lastName"
              placeholder="Enter Last Name"
              value={x.lastName}
              onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
            />

            <div className="btn-box">
              <button onClick={handleAddClick}>Add</button>}
          </div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    }
    < div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}> {JSON.stringify(this.state.inputList)}</div >
  </div >
   );
 }
}
```

Here's the code that uses hooks and it works fine:
https://www.cluemediator.com/add-or-remove-input-fields-dynamically-with-reactjs

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: it says: ./src/App.js
  Line 27:34:  'handleInputChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 34:34:  'handleInputChange' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 38:36:  'handleAddClick' is not defined     no-undef

Comment: Oh you just need to define them

Comment: I mean how? by putting "public" or "const"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: "this" is undefined inside a component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function)

Comment: I suggested the question above because it looks like you would benefit from some more information on how the context (`this`) works inside JS and React class components, but the real issue in your code is that you're missing `this` when calling the functions here: `onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}` which should be `onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e, i)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it with `this`

```
<button onClick={this.handleAddClick}>Add</button>}
```

You need to use `this` when accessing functions in a class component

Comment: sorry I forgot to add, I edited my code. Please see it

Comment: I also linked the code that uses hooks and it works fine. But when I converted it without using hooks, it's not working

Comment: Okay I updated my answer that should fix the problem