# TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating program and there I need to use smth from first component in second component. If you can help we to construct it.

My code

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  state = { items: ["Hakob", "Arman"] };

  Add() {
    const newitems = this.state.items.concat([prompt("a")]);
    this.setState({ items: newitems });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Clock2 Clock2={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Clock2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.Add}>click</button>
        {this.state.items.map((e, i) => {
          return <div key={e + i}> {e} </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

My error` TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null.

[image]

Help me please if you can...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: it doens't help, if you can edit my code please

Comment: The point of SO is to be a repository of general solutions, not to solve the same problem over and over again with different identifiers. If you have read through the information in the duplicate, fixed your code to bind `this` correctly and *still* have a problem, please [edit] to give a [mre] of that rather than just *"doesn't help"*.

Comment: <button onClick={this.props.Add}>click</button> to <button onClick={this.props.Add = () => {} ?

Comment: I would not expect that to work, no. It doesn't make sense - `Add` wasn't in `props` to begin with, and even if it was you'd be replacing it with a new no-op arrow function.

Comment: More specific to your context: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33973648/3001761

Comment: I had done it, but id didn't work. I had wrote   Add = () => {
      const newitems = this.state.items.concat([prompt('a')])
      this.setState({items:newitems})
   } but there it shows the same error

Comment: If you can please fix my problem

Comment: You still get the error because you have multiple other problems in your code. See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-currying-ipjfy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `items` and the `Add function` to `Clock2` as props. Then inside `Clock2` use the passed down props.

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  state = { items: ["Hakob", "Arman"] };

  Add = () => {
    const newitems = this.state.items.concat([prompt("a")]);
    this.setState({ items: newitems });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Clock2 items={this.state.items} Add={this.Add} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Clock2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.Add}>click</button>
        {this.props.items.map((e, i) => {
          return <div key={e + i}> {e} </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```