# Why 'this' is different in React class than in Js event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when I use this code :

```
html :  <body>
   <button>Click me</button>
   <script type="module" src="1.js"></script>
 </body>
JS : const btn = document.querySelector('button')
class Events {
 constructor() {
   console.log(this)
   btn.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick)
 }
 handleClick() {
   console.log(this)
 }
}
const event = new Events()
```

"this" = button element

But when I use this code in react:

```
class Event extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {}
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log(this)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

"this" = undefined
why 'this' in the javascript event handler is different than react event handler?

Comment: try adding this in constructor `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Comment: Thanks but actually i know all solutions. i need to know the difference for why 'this' works differently?

Comment: Try removing `btn.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick)` from constructor in your first file, will the handleClick still have `this`? This should clear it for you, if not I can go in depth

Comment: **All:** Note that the question asked above is "why is it different?" not "what do I do about it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because React's synthetic event system doesn't call your function with `this` set to the DOM element, and the DOM does. It's just the way that React's event handling is written. Instead of `yourHandler.call(theDOMElement, eventObject)` it just does `yourHandler(eventObject)`. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). If you want to access the DOM element, use the `currentTarget` property of the event object:

```
handleClick(event) {
    const element = event.currentTarget;
    // ...
}
```

That's the same element that the DOM uses for `this` (and is both a DOM property and a React property). Note that `currentTarget` and `target` are not the same thing; `target` may be an element *within* the element you hooked the event on, but `currentTarget` will always be the element you hooked the event on.

The next question might be what you do about it. That's covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).