# Getting a "TypeError" when trying to validate a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a validation function in my form, but when I test it I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleValidation' of undefined". Since I'm new to reactjs (this is my first webapp made with react) I don't seem to be able to find where the error is. The behavior of this form is: when a user clicks on submit, it first performs the validation, then if valid submit the form via email (to do this I'm using emailjs). Like I said, it fails on the validation step (while everything else works fine, even the email). I hope you can help me, here is my form component:

```
class ContactForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        fields: { 'user_name': "", 'user_email': "" },
        errors: {}
    };
}
//Functions to handle form validation

handleValidation() {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;

    //Name
    if (!fields["user_name"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_name"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
    }

    if (typeof fields["user_name"] !== "undefined") {
        if (!fields["user_name"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["user_name"] = "Solo lettere";
        }
    }

    //Email
    if (!fields["user_email"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_email"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
    }

    if (typeof fields["user_email"] !== "undefined") {
        let lastAtPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('@');
        let lastDotPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('.');

        if (!(lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && fields["user_email"].indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (fields["user_email"].length - lastDotPos) > 2)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["user_email"] = "Email non valida";
        }
    }

    this.setState({ errors: errors });
    return formIsValid;
}

handleChange(field, e) {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ fields });
}


sendEmail(e) {
    let submitSuccess = document.getElementById('success');
    let submitFailed = document.getElementById('failed');
    let contactNumber = document.getElementById('contact_number');
    let userName = document.getElementById('user_name');
    let userMail = document.getElementById('user_email');
    let userMessage = document.getElementById('message');


    e.preventDefault();
    //Generate random 5-digit number for the contact number
    contactNumber.value = Math.random() * 100000 | 0;

    if (this.handleValidation) {
        emailjs.sendForm(/*informations to send email*/)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.text);
                submitSuccess.style.display = 'block';
                userName.style.value = '';
                userMail.style.value = '';
                userMessage.style.value = '';
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error.text);
                submitFailed.style.display = 'block';
            })
    } else {
        alert("Ci sono errori nel form");
    };
```

}

```
render() {
    return (
        <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={this.sendEmail}>
            <input type="hidden" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" value="" />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" style={InputFormCSS} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "user_name")} value={this.state.fields["user_name"]} required />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_mail" style={InputFormCSS} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "user_email")} value={this.state.fields["user_email"]} required />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" style={TextareaFormCSS} required />
            <input type="submit" value="Invia" />
            <p id="success" style={{ display: 'none', backgroundColor: 'green', color: 'white', fontSize: '1.1em', borderRadius: 5, padding: 10 }}>Il messaggio è stato inviato con successo</p>
            <p id="failed" style={{ display: 'none', backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white', fontSize: '1.1em', borderRadius: 5, padding: 10 }}>Non è stato possibile inviare il messaggio</p>
        </form>


    );
}
```

}

Comment: If you're using React, why are you doing `document.getElementById`? React handles DOM interaction for you -- that's a good chunk of the whole point of the library. Anyway, don't forget to bind `this` in the constructor to your functions to avoid this error. Or use function components and `useState`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: "this" is undefined inside a component function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function)

Comment: Unfortunately even by using the bind in the constructor hasn't solved the issue, I still get the undefined error. Any more suggestions? (like I said, I'm new in react, I'm still learning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to bind the function `handleValidation` in constructor.

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        fields: { user_name: "", user_email: "" },
        errors: {}
    };
    this.handleValidation = this.handleValidation.bind(this);
    this.sendEmail = this.sendEmail.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
//Functions to handle form validation

handleValidation() {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;

    //Name
    if (!fields["user_name"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_name"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
    }

    if (typeof fields["user_name"] !== "undefined") {
        if (!fields["user_name"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["user_name"] = "Solo lettere";
        }
    }

    if (!fields["user_email"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_email"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
    }

    if (typeof fields["user_email"] !== "undefined") {
        let lastAtPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('@');
        let lastDotPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('.');

        if (!(lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && fields["user_email"].indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (fields["user_email"].length - lastDotPos) > 2)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["user_email"] = "Email non valida";
        }
    }

    this.setState({ errors: errors });
    return formIsValid;
}

handleChange(field, e) {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ fields });
}


sendEmail(e) {
    let submitSuccess = document.getElementById('success');
    let submitFailed = document.getElementById('failed');
    let contactNumber = document.getElementById('contact_number');
    let userName = document.getElementById('user_name');
    let userMail = document.getElementById('user_email');
    let userMessage = document.getElementById('message');


    e.preventDefault();
    //Generate random 5-digit number for the contact number
    contactNumber.value = Math.random() * 100000 | 0;

    if (this.handleValidation) {
        emailjs.sendForm(/*informations to send email*/)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.text);
                submitSuccess.style.display = 'block';
                userName.style.value = '';
                userMail.style.value = '';
                userMessage.style.value = '';
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error.text);
                submitFailed.style.display = 'block';
            })
    } else {
        alert("Ci sono errori nel form");
    };
}
  render() {
    return (
        <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={this.sendEmail}>
            <input type="hidden" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" value="" />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "user_name")} value={this.state.fields["user_name"]} required />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_mail" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "user_email")} value={this.state.fields["user_email"]} required />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required />
            <input type="submit" value="Invia" />
            <p id="success" style={{ display: 'none', backgroundColor: 'green', color: 'white', fontSize: '1.1em', borderRadius: 5, padding: 10 }}>Il messaggio è stato inviato con successo</p>
            <p id="failed" style={{ display: 'none', backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white', fontSize: '1.1em', borderRadius: 5, padding: 10 }}>Non è stato possibile inviare il messaggio</p>
        </form>


    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Second Scenario

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        fields: { user_name: "", user_email: "" },
        errors: {}
    };
    }
//Functions to handle form validation

handleValidation = () => {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;

    //Name
    if (!fields["user_name"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_name"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
    }

    if (typeof fields["user_name"] !== "undefined") {
        if (!fields["user_name"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["user_name"] = "Solo lettere";
        }
    }

    if (!fields["user_email"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_email"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
    }

    if (typeof fields["user_email"] !== "undefined") {
        let lastAtPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('@');
        let lastDotPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('.');

        if (!(lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && fields["user_email"].indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (fields["user_email"].length - lastDotPos) > 2)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["user_email"] = "Email non valida";
        }
    }

    this.setState({ errors: errors });
    return formIsValid;
}

handleChange = (field, e) => {
    let fields = this.state.fields;
    fields[field] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ fields });
}


sendEmail = (e) => {
    let submitSuccess = document.getElementById('success');
    let submitFailed = document.getElementById('failed');
    let contactNumber = document.getElementById('contact_number');
    let userName = document.getElementById('user_name');
    let userMail = document.getElementById('user_email');
    let userMessage = document.getElementById('message');


    e.preventDefault();
    //Generate random 5-digit number for the contact number
    contactNumber.value = Math.random() * 100000 | 0;

    if (this.handleValidation) {
        emailjs.sendForm(/*informations to send email*/)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result.text);
                submitSuccess.style.display = 'block';
                userName.style.value = '';
                userMail.style.value = '';
                userMessage.style.value = '';
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error.text);
                submitFailed.style.display = 'block';
            })
    } else {
        alert("Ci sono errori nel form");
    };
}
  render() {
    return (
        <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={this.sendEmail}>
            <input type="hidden" id="contact_number" name="contact_number" value="" />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Nome</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "user_name")} value={this.state.fields["user_name"]} required />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_mail" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "user_email")} value={this.state.fields["user_email"]} required />
            <label style={{ fontSize: '1.3em' }}>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required />
            <input type="submit" value="Invia" />
            <p id="success" style={{ display: 'none', backgroundColor: 'green', color: 'white', fontSize: '1.1em', borderRadius: 5, padding: 10 }}>Il messaggio è stato inviato con successo</p>
            <p id="failed" style={{ display: 'none', backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white', fontSize: '1.1em', borderRadius: 5, padding: 10 }}>Non è stato possibile inviare il messaggio</p>
        </form>


    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance

EDIT: Updated Class constructor

Comment: Sadly this doesn't solve my issue, I'm still getting the same error. Any more suggestion?

Comment: @liveAndrew Can you check now. Every function in a Class component must be bind within constructor or it should be an arrow function. For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance

Comment: **Except for render and constructor

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you Abhishek Saxena and @jatin-parmar, what actually solved the problem was to put every function inside the component as arrow function. I accepted Abhishek's answer just because he answered first, but indeed this was the solution, so thanks to you both again.
Now, there is another problem and I don't know if I can ask here or if I should make a new post, but basically the validation doesn't work: I mean, if try to send a blank form, the validation gives the ok and the form is sent! ^^" Where is the error in the logic?

Answer (score 0):

you should use arrow function to define all methods of you component ,this will auto bind this with the method like
`

```
handleValidation=()=> {
let fields = this.state.fields;
let errors = {};
let formIsValid = true;

//Name
if (!fields["user_name"]) {
    formIsValid = false;
    errors["user_name"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
}

if (typeof fields["user_name"] !== "undefined") {
    if (!fields["user_name"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_name"] = "Solo lettere";
    }
}

if (!fields["user_email"]) {
    formIsValid = false;
    errors["user_email"] = "Non può essere vuoto!";
}

if (typeof fields["user_email"] !== "undefined") {
    let lastAtPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('@');
    let lastDotPos = fields["user_email"].lastIndexOf('.');

    if (!(lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && fields["user_email"].indexOf('@@') == -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (fields["user_email"].length - lastDotPos) > 2)) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["user_email"] = "Email non valida";
    }
}

this.setState({ errors: errors });
return formIsValid;
}
```

`
you will need to define all methods this way