# value of this inside the eventHandler in class based component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am new to the React and little confused here

```
export default class Message extends Component {

    m1() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.m1}>Click 1</button>
        );
    }
}
```

Why value of this is not the button element itself?

Why it refer to the caller object ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Why it refer to the caller object ?"* ? I'm afraid that question is unclear. By default, `this` **won't** refer to any object in a `class` component event handler, it'll be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

> value of this inside the eventHandler in class based component

As described in the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), React doesn't do anything to set `this` to any specific value, so if you do `onClick={myFunction}`, it's equivalent to calling `myFunction(event)`. In JavaScript, calling a function that way uses the default `this` value, which is `undefined` in strict mode (`class` code is always strict). This is different from how `addEventListener` works, where the DOM event system sets `this` to the element the event handler is attached to when calling the function.

> Why value of this is not the button element itself?

A design choice by the React team. If you want the element that the event handler was attached to, you can get it from the event object your handler is passed using `event.currentTarget` (this is also true with `addEventHandler` handlers in non-React code; `this` and `event.currentTarget` have the same value by default).

> Why it refer to the caller object ?

It doesn't. If you mean how can you make it refer to the instance of the class component, see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). The usual solutions are to use `bind` on the event handler function, or to use a wrapper arrow function (more in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function)).

For instance, re your code, you might bind `m1` in your constructor:

```
export default class Message extends Component {
    constructor(props) {                // ***
        super(props);                   // ***
        this.m1 = this.m1.bind(this);   // ***
    }                                   // ***
    m1() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.m1}>Click 1</button>
        );
    }
}
```

**Or**, you might just do a wrapper arrow function where you call it:

```
return (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(event) => this.m1(event)}>Click 1</button>
        {/* −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    */}
);
```

**Or**, some people assign an arrow function to a class field instead of using method syntax:

```
export default class Message extends Component {
    m1 = () => {                    // ***
        console.log("Hello world"); // ***
    };                              // ***
    render() {
        return (
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.m1}>Click 1</button>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm not a fan of that because it means the method isn't on the prototype, which is handy for several reasons (including mocking for tests), but it's an option.

Comment: In HTML when we do: ` <button id='btn1' onclick='console.log(this.id);'>Click</button>`  **The this refers to the button element here** But in the above question **this** does not refer to the button element

Comment: @LakashDangol - Yes, as I said above, that's a difference between React and DOM event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> onClick={this.m1}
> ```

The value between `{` and `}` is an *expression* that is evaluated when the function it is inside (`render()` in this case) is called.

So the value of `this` from the scope of `render()` and depends on how `render()` is called (exceptions for `bind`, arrow functions, etc aside).

In this case, the result of the expression is the function `m1` which is assigned to the `onClick` prop of the `button` component.

---

This is different from the HTML `onclick` **attribute** which accepts a string representing a function body which is evaluated **when the client event** fires.