# React: Populating select dropdown options from an API Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, dropdown, html-select

so I am trying to populate a select dropdown option menu with values returned from a GET call to my API.  I currently have code that successfully returns a list of values based on a location that the user enters. I also have a dropdown menu created to display the results, but currently it is not working. I believe I may be incorrectly using state / setState.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqRFp.png)

Essentially, if the user type '1449' in the textbox, the dropdown options should be 'PAAF' and 'EXLA'.

The API get call returns a list of carriers in string format, as such:

```
[
    "PAAF",
    "EXLA"
]
```

The code for the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class FetchCarrierList extends React.Component {

  state = {
    carriers: []
  }

  render() {

    function loadCarriers(url) {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: url
      }).then((response) => {
        let relCarriers = response.data;
        console.log(relCarriers);
        **this.setState({relCarriers});**
      }).catch((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Error communicating with server');
      });
    }

    function getData(val) {
      let location = val.target.value;
      let baseUrl = "http://localhost:6012/myAPI/carrier/getCarriersByLocation/" + location;
      if (location.length === 4) {
        loadCarriers(baseUrl);
      }
    }

    return <div className="editPro">
      <h1>Edit Pro Numbers</h1>
      <div id="carrierSelection">
        <input type="text" id="locationEntry" onChange={getData}></input>
        <select id="carrierDropDown">
          <option selected disabled>Select A Carrier</option>
          {this.state.carriers.map(option => <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>)}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you bound your methods in your constructor? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function

Answer (score 0):

Your state has one property which is **carriers**

```
state = {
  carriers: []
}
```

but when you set your state after the API response you set it to **relCarriers**

```
this.setState({relCarriers});
```

which doesn't exist on the state.
Instead, you should set it like this

```
this.setState({carriers: relCarriers});
```

Or you can rename the variable where you store response.data to, to carriers and then set it like this

```
let carriers = response.data;
this.setState({carriers});
```

The reason why it doesn't work with just **relCarriers** is because you are assigning the value with shorthand property assignment - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, after changing I still unfortunately get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')
    at FetchCarrierList.js:20:1"

Comment: @Austin, gloo is actually right. You have to bind the component context to promise then method, so then you can point to the component.