# TypeError: this.setState is not a function react js

Tags: reactjs

whats happend setstate is not function?!!! 
could you please help me for this error ?
its just very simple but not work

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'http://192.168.1.156:8000/api/v1/reports/',
   data: {'start':start.toLocaleUpperCase(),'end':end.toLocaleLowerCase()},
   success: function (result) {
     var LoginData = JSON.parse(result.reports.login);
     this.setState({Data:LoginData});
     console.log(LoginData[0].username);
     console.log(LoginData[0].last_login);
   }.bind(this),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [purpose of .bind(this) at end of ajax callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285581/purpose-of-bindthis-at-end-of-ajax-callback)

Comment: can you remove the bing this i believe this binding makes the scope of the this.setstate scoped to the ajax function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-state-or-props-of-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503559/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-state-or-props-of-undefined/39503728#39503728)

Comment: You might not be binding the function in which you have the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

It don't work because of asynchronous. when success function executed, this is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In React JS setState works only on event

don't try this

```
 ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://192.168.1.156:8000/api/v1/reports/',
       data: {'start':start.toLocaleUpperCase(),'end':end.toLocaleLowerCase()},
       success: function (result) {
         var LoginData = JSON.parse(result.reports.login);
         this.setState({Data:LoginData});
         console.log(LoginData[0].username);
         console.log(LoginData[0].last_login);
       }.bind(this)
    }
```

Try this

```
ajaxCall = (e) => {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://192.168.1.156:8000/api/v1/reports/',
       data: {'start':start.toLocaleUpperCase(),'end':end.toLocaleLowerCase()},
       success: function (result) {
         var LoginData = JSON.parse(result.reports.login);
         this.setState({Data:LoginData});
         console.log(LoginData[0].username);
         console.log(LoginData[0].last_login);
       }.bind(this),
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).